# How to provide option to render pdf to end user system using phantomjs

Tags: node.js, pdf, phantomjs

I am using phantomjs node module to render pdf. Below is my code for pdf genration

```
 phantom.create(function ( ph) {
            ph.createPage(function ( page) {
                page.set('paperSize',
                    {
                        format: 'A4',
                        orientation: 'potrait',
                        border:'1cm'
                    }
                );


                page.set('content', html, function () {
                    page.render('../../../output.pdf', function () {
                        ph.exit();
                    });
                    ph.exit();
                    callback();
                });
            });
        });
```

page is rendered properly.Currently it is saved on the server. But I need to provide an option for the end user to select the location where he wants to render the PDF. Is it possible? How can I do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How end user executes your render script? Via a browser then downloads it?

Comment: The user can specify a location on your server? The user could download the file and save it where ever they'd like via `Save As` in the browser.

Comment: This script is run on the node server.After the page is rendered on the server, in the callback function(callback will run client side on  browser) i need to  download that rendered file to the user's system).